# Find rank of participant in various contests sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a participant table:

```
userid   name
1        John
2        Sam
3        Harry
```

And there is contest table:

```
contestid contestname
1         abc
2         def
3         ghi
```

Score table looks like this:

```
id  contestid userid score
1   1         1      200
2   1         2      300
3   1         3      250
4   2         1      500
5   2         2      400
6   3         2      800
```

Now, given an `userid`, I need to find out his rank in all the contest.
The Rank should be based on Contest and Score.

Output should be like this for `userid=1`:

```
contestid rank
1         3
2         1
3         Nil
```

How can I get this output?

Comment: And what have you tried that isn't working?  This is a simple `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN` query.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you need it Rank by Score and Contest then try this

---

```
SET @rank := 0;
SET @prev := NULL;

SELECT contestid,userid,score,Rank FROM
(
SELECT contestid,userid,score,@rank := IF(@prev = contestid, @rank + 1, 1) AS rank,
       @prev := contestid
FROM scores ORDER BY contestid, score DESC
) S Where userid = 1
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d0eb4/18)

---

**2.** If you need it Rank by Score then try this

---

```
SELECT contestid,userid,score, FIND_IN_SET( score, 
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY score DESC) FROM scores)) AS rank
FROM scores
Where UserId = 1
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d0eb4/1)

---

**3.** If you want UserName and COntest Name then try this

---

```
SELECT C.contestname,P.name,S.score, FIND_IN_SET( S.score, 
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY score DESC) FROM scores)) AS rank
FROM scores S Join participant P ON P.userid =C.userid 
              Join contest  C ON C.contestid = S.contestid 
Where UserId = 1
```

Comment: From your query, user with userid 1 is getting rank 6 for contest 1 for Fiddle sample table.

Comment: @user2779912 Do you need to rank it by score or score and contest??

Comment: Score and contest both. Rank should be evaluated for each of the contest based on corresponding scores. Thanks for help.